# File drop Automation _ Exception mechanism

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, files

I am trying to get a solution for a unique exception case of File drop automation.

The scenario is, a file(with wrong data) is dropped into FTP, overwrites a Data extension and waits for 2 hours and then triggers a journey to send out the emails.
During this delay of 2 hours, a new file (with correct data) is dropped into FTP within an hour. 
Here the 1st file drop automation is in progress while the second one waits in the queue.

Is there a way to stop the email triggering from the 1st automation since it had bad data with any automation activity?

Comment: What do you mean by “bad data”?

Comment: Wrong data - the data is in a good format. But just that we don't want to send emails to the data contacts. Bad data in terms of business I can say

Comment: Can you 100% guarantee that a “correct” data file will always come through <2 hours after the “bad” data file; and they always come through in that order (bad, good, bad, good, etc)? Do you have access to the system/processes that send the bad/good data files? Are the bad and good files exactly the same data structure?

Comment: @CameronRobert, 2 hours of delay is from the file drop to sending email.

Comment: Hi CloudDot, can you please provide additional detail (questions above).

Comment: @CameronRobert, I don't have access to the system which is pushing data file. bad data files have the same data structure.

Comment: @CameronRobert there is no regular pattern or frequency of the file coming into FTO

Comment: Is there any sort of 'flag' inside the data to denote if it is 'good' or 'bad'? How are you able to differentiate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:
 - Consistent file name & structure
 - Consistent file drops/timing

Solution: Skip every 2nd file drop.
You can setup an Automation Studio activity to trigger/start on file drop to a specified FTP location.
In the automation, load the data file and do any data processing and email sends needed. Then set a “wait” activity for 2 hours. This 2 hour wait activity will ensure the automation is still running when the next (bad) data file comes through.
If you disable queuing, the automation will skip the command to run again, thus “skipping” every 2nd file that is uploaded.

If you time this correctly, it will achieve your goal of only running/processing every 2nd file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try this solution.